# How to see if Vim has a file opened or not, or has a buffer open

Tags: buffers

Sometimes I want to open vim in preparation of opening a file in the directory tree.

So i start it without a file:

```
vim
```

Then I use a map to open NERDTree:

```
:NERDTreeFind<CR>
```

This fails with

```
NERDTree: no file for the current buffer
```

OK so this is perhaps a deficiency in the plugin, and I want to add a check (either to use inside my bind, or to PR upstream to handle this edge case for the plugin).

How do I check that I am in a `[No Name]` buffer? `@%`? `:f`?

Answer (score 5):

```
nnoremap <Leader>f :call SmartNERDTree()<CR>

function! SmartNERDTree()                   
    if @% == ""
        NERDTreeToggle                      
    else                                    
        NERDTreeFind                        
    endif                                   
endfun
```

I'm sure it would be possible to make it a oneliner in the map. The question is about whether it would be more readable.

Comment: Use a map expression to get a one-liner, e.g. `nnoremap <expr> <leader>f ':call ' . (@% == '' ? 'NERDTreeToggle' : 'NERDTreeFind') . "\<cr>"`. See `:h :map-expression`. However, I feel readability is more important as you may want make edits in the future and functions can be simpler for such cases.

Comment: Do you know if the `expr` is _required_? It makes maintenance a lot less palatable. I know I can make an `if` with `|`s inline and all that. But `?` conditional operator would be somewhat more elegant. I just a bit of trouble finding out whether vimscript even has that operator. it seems that it does...

Comment: You can do it many ways if you don't want to use `<expr>`. Use `:execute`, e.g. `nnoremap <leader>f :execute (@% == '' ? 'NERDTreeToggle' : 'NERDTreeFind')<cr>` or use `<c-r>=` e.g. `nnoremap <leader>f :<c-r>=@% == '' ? 'NERDTreeToggle' : 'NERDTreeFind'<cr><cr>` or as you say with an `:if` and `|`, e.g. `nnoremap <leader>f :if @% == ""<bar> NERDTreeToggle<bar>else<bar> NERDTreeFind<bar>endif<cr>`

Comment: I'm sort of joking but sort of not. This discussion only re-confirms the notion that VimScript is a horrible, horrible language. ;) Could you spell it out more plainly why a ternary cannot actually be put directly into a `map`?

Comment: This is an "statement" vs expression issue, e.g. `:set filetype=python` vs `:let &filetype=somefunc(arg)`. Anything that is sourced or executed via command-line(`:`) is a statement/command. A command may take a certain syntax or sometimes an expression. I used `:execute` above because `:execute` takes an expression and then executes it as a command. It is can be a tricky. I would recommend reading `:h eval` (actually whole manual would be best). May also want to look into [Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/) by Steve Losh.